# ImportError: No module names 'matplotlib' Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm new to python (started 2 days ago) and I have gotten to the point where I want to use matplotlib for my program. I am using python 3.3 and after I have followed the instructions of installing matplotlib I've gone through the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

That returned this import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

So after some research I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplot
```

I'm still getting the same import error. I have found this page here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/427708/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-matplotlib-even-though-it-is-installed

This has given me the impression that I have installed the incorrect version of matplotlib and that I need v1.2 or higher. Can someone explain to me what I need to do to be able to use matplotlib and not get this error with Python 3.3?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On my Mint 17 I just did, with Python 3.4 (would recommend that as you just start with Python, unless you need some library which does not yet support 3.4):

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Then test the install:

```
python3

import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
```

Should give you '1.4.0'

Comment: 2.1.0                           is what I got

Answer (score 0):

I am using python3 installed through anaconda3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo <path to anaconda>/anaconda3/bin/conda install matplotlib
```

Path to anaconda installation directory can be found using:

```
conda info --envs
```